# Is there a Disk mounter indicator?

Tags: mount, indicator

Well - just because I cannot find this asked anywhere else on the net - is there something like a "Disk Mounter" applet for Unity interface, or are there any alternatives?

(By 'alternatives' I mean: I wouldn't mind doubleclicking an icon, and have what used to be a toolbar applet start up as a separate window; as long as don't have to grapple with `mount` command lines, and filesystem arguments and such.)

Comment: Yes, i need the same good as mention on the Q. Sometimes we need to quickly mount a partition from an application such as media player, editor or something like that, and to open nautilus first is a waste of time :-) so it will be great if we could mount the partition or disk (other harddisk) directly from the unity panel or search box. Especially when we already make a bookmark on the Open File Dialog.

Comment: safely remove hardware http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ejecter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You should try Mounty - an indicator applet you can use to easily mount CD / DVD images (and can also burn them directly from the appindicator).

You have to add the ppa `ppa:tldm217/tahutek.net`to your software sources ([here's how to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBy9t.png)) and install mounty from the software center.

Your question actually inspired my post: [Indicator Applet To Mount CD / DVD Images: Mounty](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/indicator-applet-to-mount-cd-dvd-images.html) :)

Comment: Hi @Alin Andrei, thanks and +1 for your answer! However, as far as I can see, `Mounty` is apparently meant for mounting ISO images; my primary need is with mounting unmounted partitions (which the old mounter applet can visualise, and mount with a single click). Thanks again for the `mounty` tip - cheers!

Comment: Oh, I've understood your question wrong then. Sorry... I still don't understand exactly what you want though: you can simply click a drive to mount/unmount it from Nautilus.

Comment: Hi @Alin Andrei - you're absolutely right; can't believe I missed that, and it was in front of me all the time :) I guess I just got too used to the disk mounter applet (ok, I guess one could argue, you could mount without Nautilus open etc)... But still, that solution is good enough for me :) Will put an accept here (at least until a "real" disk mounter comes out for Unity - if ever :) ) ... Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: Mounty is not a replacement for Disk Mounter, nor is Nautilus. If you're connecting and disconnecting drives all the time, like in the forensic area where I work, there seems to be no Unity replacement for Disk Mounter. I searched for a nearly an hour on the internet but didn't find anything comparable and simple as good old Disk Mounter. That's a pity - and a reason to switch away from Unity back to Gnome. So, the question remains unanswered and doesn't merit a green dot in the overview list.

Comment: Perhaps the indicator I wrote might do what you want, at least partially :)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>disclaimer: I am the author of this indicator</sub>

#### udisks-indicator

This indicator has been written originally for a [different AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/830558/295286), however it fulfills the requirements of this question as well.  Its primary purpose is to display mounted and unmounted partitions, however clicking on the unmounted partitions menu entries mounts the clicked partition. The indicator doesn't unmount a partition, but that can be done via Gnome Disks Utility, which is openable via this indicator.

By default the user interface shows all menu entries, but via Preferences dialog , users can remove certain fields to make the menu more compact

Below is the screenshot of user interface:
[image]

User interface with all optional fields off:

[image]

#### Installation:

To install from PPA, use the following steps in terminal:

1. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:udisks-indicator-team/ppa`
2. `sudo bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install udisks-indicator'`

Version 1.0 source code is available in the linked AskUbuntu question. The latest source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/udisks-indicator).  You can use the following script for easy installation from GitHub

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
rm master.zip*
wget https://github.com/SergKolo/udisks-indicator/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
install udisks-indicator-master/udisks-indicator /usr/bin/udisks-indicator
install udisks-indicator-master/udisks-indicator.desktop /usr/share/applications/udisks-indicator.desktop
```