# How to display partition used/free space in Nautilus like in Windows?

Tags: nautilus

Is there anyway to show partition used/free space like this screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The default file manager, Nautilus , doesn't have such functionality. To my knowledge there's  no file manager out there that provides such functionality either.

You can, however, visualize usage by right clicking on each mounted (!) disk partition in the right side panel, via Properties menu:

[image]

There are  alternative ways, for instance via Disk Usage Analyzer, as Ben suggested. I've written a [Udisks Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/830558/295286), which shows mounted partitions and their usage in top-right panel, so that could be another alternative. Screenshot is below.

[image]

There's also `df` and more user-friendly `pydf` program, which will allow you to show mounted filesystem usage in command line

```
$ df -h | grep '^/dev'                                                                                                   
/dev/sda1       110G   62G   43G  59% /
/dev/sdb6       399G  149G  230G  40% /mnt/HDD
$ pydf
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use%                              Mounted on          
/dev/sda1  110G  61G   43G 55.9 [###############...........] /                   
/dev/sdb6  399G 149G  230G 37.3 [##########................] /mnt/HDD            
/dev/sda1  110G  61G   43G 55.9 [###############...........] /var/lib/docker/aufs
```

There's plenty of [other alternatives](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/) , but if you want it done specifically via Nautilus, then answer is unfortunately it's not possible. But you can always submit a feature request to the developers, which I think would be a quite useful feature to have, and community might agree with you.

Comment: This seems very nice. I got this error while installing the indicator

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/udisks-indicator-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: @hosam.shafik yeah, that's because you're using Wily , which is 15.04, and it's not supported anymore.  You're also using 32-bit version OS, judging from the address it was trying to fetch. Get the indicator from github, https://github.com/SergKolo/udisks-indicator. I'd really recommend you upgrade to 16.04, because a lot of software drops support for older releases

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Nautlius provides this functionality, but you might find what you're looking for in Disk Usage Analyzer. (If you don't have it installed, run `sudo apt-get install baobab` in a terminal.)

Comment: I have a lot files in my HDD. I just want to find easy way to manage partitions instead of keep checking properties of each partition