# Is it possible to show ip address on top bar near the time?

Tags: 17.10

Is it possible to show IP address on top bar near the time? I use ubuntu 17.10 and Xorg.

Here the Image:

[image]

Comment: There should be some extensions for that on http://extensions.gnome.org

Comment: I find it, thanks for the tip: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/941/show-ip/

Comment: @rkpisanu Please post it as an answer below. It's completely fine (and very much encouraged) to answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

### Screenshot

[image: indicator sysmonitor screenshot.png]

### Discover your current DCHP IP address

This answer should work for most Ubuntu distributions. The first step is discovering your current IP address. According to this [Linux & Unix answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178256/200094) it isn't stored on disk in the same location across distributions. For a portable solution you need to use:

```
default_interface=$(route -n | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0" {print $8; exit}')
ip_address=$(ifconfig "$default_interface" | awk 'sub(/.* inet addr:/, "") {print $1}')
echo $ip_address
192.168.1.66
```

### Install Sysmonitor Indicator

You now need an Application Indicator that to let's you pick and choose the information to display in the Systray / Application Notification Area. I use [Sysmonitor Indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/ubuntu-appindicator-that-displays-bash.html). To summarize the installation instructions in the link:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

You need to configure the name of the bash script that is called and the update interval in the `Advanced` tab of the `Preferences` panel:

[image: indicator sysmonitor custom.png]

Highlight the `Custom` option and click the `Edit` button:

[image: indicator sysmonitor custom edit.png]

Here's a complaint I have to the developer the input field for the command is abnormally small. You can't see the whole command you are typing all at once and need arrow keys to scroll through it. Anyway assign the bash script filename. I used:

```
~/bin/indicator-sysmonitor-display
```

I already have a main bash script so I created an abbreviated version for this answer.

### Create the script

Using the code from the first section create the file `~/bin/indicator-sysmonitor-display` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

default_interface=$(route -n | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0" {print $8; exit}')
systray=$(ifconfig "$default_interface" | awk 'sub(/.* inet addr:/, "") {print $1}')

echo "$systray" # sysmon-indidicator will put echo string into systray for us.

exit 0
```

Comment: Change the script to this

`#!/bin/bash

default_interface=$(route -n | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0" {print $8; exit}')
systray=$(ifconfig "$default_interface" | awk 'sub(/.* inet /, "") {print $1}')

echo "$systray" # sysmon-indidicator will put echo string into systray for us.

exit 0`

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you want to see your Local IP address (not public IP), the Gnome Shell Extension [LAN IP Address](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1762/lan-ip-address/) should meet your needs. Unlike the Show IP extension, this one is actively supported (as of 2022).

Full disclosure, I am the author of this extension.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Show IP](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/941/show-ip/) which does

> Show IP addresses (private or public) in gnome-shell bar

[image]

<sub>*Source*: A [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024866/is-it-possible-to-show-ip-address-on-top-bar-near-the-time#comment1665080_1024866) by OP which should have been posted as an answer instead.</sub>

Comment: This solution is not working on Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems that development is discontinued. https://github.com/sgaraud/gnome-extension-show-ip/issues/31 https://github.com/sgaraud/gnome-extension-show-ip/issues/27