# Is there a GNOME extension which can run a specific command and update its output as status in GNOME panel?

Tags: unity, gnome-shell, gnome-panel, gnome-shell-extension

To give an example, I run series of commands which would output a number. I must show this on the GNOME panel. Font, color, size etc doesn't matter. I just need a small display on the panel.

Comment: By gnome panel do you mean Systray / application indicator area? If so I haven't tried it yet but you can search on `indicator-sysmonitor`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Consider linking your pizza script, maybe it's exactly what OP needs

Comment: Rohit, please read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/882419/can-bash-display-in-systray-as-application-indicator/882420#882420 @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for the reminder. I was on my phone when I posted comment so did not have search & linking abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of extensions you might want to have a look at.

1. [Top Bar Script Executor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1154/top-bar-script-executor/)

   > Adds buttons to the top bar that execute scripts or commands.
2. [Command Output](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/912/command-output/)

   > Display the output of a shell command at a user-specified interval.

Comment: Both extensions seem to be abandoned

Comment: There's Executor that seems to be actively maintained : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2932/executor/. Tested, works fine (Gnome 3.38).

Answer (score 1):

Executor by raujonas, logo has a Sigma sign on it

does exactly what you want - I use it to ping a server and display and Up/Down arrow in the panel.
Install via https://extensions.gnome.org/ or use Tweaks > extensions

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Argos](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1176/argos/) (and here's an [article about it](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/argos-is-like-bitbar-for-gnome-shell-it.html)).